# Export of Video file using PHImageManager fails:AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" Code=-12212

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary

I am trying to export a video asset from camera roll on a simulator using PHImageManager from the Photos iOS SDK. When the export completion block executes, it results in this error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12212), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001baa4c0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12212 "(null)"}}

This happens every time with the specified video on the simulator's camera roll. However, this inconsistently occurs on a real device; some videos exporting fine, some not.

Why is this happening, how to fix it, and where can I find the error code documentation?

Here is the function it happens in:

```
public func exportVideoFile(
        options: PHVideoRequestOptions? = nil,
        outputURL: URL? = nil,
        outputFileType: AVFileType = .mov,
        progressBlock: ((Double) -> Void)? = nil,
        completionBlock: @escaping ((URL, String) -> Void)
    ) {
        guard
            let phAsset = self.phAsset,
            phAsset.mediaType == .video,
            let writeURL = videoFilename(phAsset: phAsset),
            let mimetype = MIMEType(writeURL)
        else { return }

        var requestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        if let options = options {
            requestOptions = options
        } else {
            requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            requestOptions.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
        }
        requestOptions.progressHandler = { progress, _, _, _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                debugPrint("progress", progress)
                progressBlock?(progress)
            }
        }

        PHImageManager.default().requestExportSession(
            forVideo: phAsset, options: requestOptions,
            exportPreset: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
        ) { session, _ in
            guard let session = session else { return }

            session.outputURL = writeURL
            session.outputFileType = outputFileType
            session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

            session.exportAsynchronously {
                completionBlock(writeURL, mimetype)
                
                if let err = session.error { // Error happens here
                    debugPrint("Video Export Session Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    debugPrint("Video Export Session Status: \(session.status)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Code=-12212" refers to the following error: kVTColorCorrectionPixelTransferFailedErr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I found out the error code "-12212" refers to kVTColorCorrectionPixelTransferFailedErr.

So I thought it's got to be a preset or quality setting issue...

I had previously tried setting `requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat` but that did not work. However, I noticed the following call had a preset for quality:

```
PHImageManager.default().requestExportSession(
            forVideo: phAsset, options: requestOptions,
            exportPreset: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
        )
```

When I changed it to this:

```
PHImageManager.default().requestExportSession(
            forVideo: phAsset, options: requestOptions,
            exportPreset: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
        )
```

It worked!

Comment: I found the code from this web site: https://www.osstatus.com/

Comment: I have same problem only with iOS 14.5 for some videos and keeping `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` does not help.

Comment: @SunilChauhan you can try setting var `requestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()` to `requestOptions.deliveryMode = .automatic` or `.highQualityFormat`

Comment: `.automatic` is the default so maybe one of the other options